# Plotting grouped data in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Plotting data.
x.values are 16-23 (age)
and for every year (16-23) I have 5 different values between 1 and ten for each age.
I want a scatterplot, all five values for each age plotted and then have a regression line and calculate the correlation after that.

```
x <- (16:23)
y<- c(10,8,9,9,8,7,8,6,9,6,6,7,7,8,5,5,8,4,7,6,8,7,6,8,4,6,5,7,5,3,5,1,3,4,2,4,1,2,5)

Studie <- plot(cbind(x, y))
```

It's just random plots for y. Idk how to get the plot

Comment: You get exactly what you are asking for - a scatterplot with age in the x axis and the values in `Studie$y` plotted against it.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand your problem, I will do like that:

```
x <- rep(16:23, each=5)
y<- c(10,8,9,9,8,7,8,6,9,6,6,7,7,8,5,5,8,4,7,6,8,7,6,8,4,6,5,7,5,3,5,1,3,4,2,4,1,2,5, 2)
plot(x,y,col=x-15)
reg <- lm(y~x)
summary(reg)
lines(x, reg$fitted.values)
```

be careful, a value is missing in vector y. I've added 2 at the end

the regression line is:
y = -0.7929 x + 21.2357